# carrierwave default_url how to display in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, upload, carrierwave

Carrierwave supports the default_url for if there is no image attached,

I have this set like:

```
  def default_url
    "/assets/avatars/" + [version_name, "_default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
```

Using a helper method like:

```
  def show_avatar(id)
    @profile = User.find(id).profile rescue nil
    image_tag @profile.assets.first.file_url(:search) rescue nil
  end
```

How would this to be refactored, so that it displays the default_url image when there is no image? I could not find this, now using a rescue nil because if there is no image attached it would crash.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but I'm sure in this case you would just do

```
image_tag model.mount.version.url
```

If there is no version or file then carrierwave uses the default url

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by doing this:

```
Image.new.file.url(:version)
```

Where `Image` is my model where I'm attaching uploader to the `file` field. Hope it helps.